# Preg_match for next line

Tags: php, preg-match

There is a pattern in my texts and I need a preg_match pattern for next line.

```
Administrative Contact:
xxxx xxxxx

this is like this sometimes :

Admin contact: 
xxxxxx xxxx
or 
admin data:
xxxx xxxx
```

Is it possible to write a regular expression for this ?
I need xxxx xxxx data

Thank You Guys

Comment: Is this part of a large piece of text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the common factors are:

- Starts with "admin"
- Has a `:` to separate the label from the data
- Has data until the end of a line

In this case, the regex is:

```
/admin[^:]*:\s*(.*)/i
```

The desired data will be in subpattern 1.