# preg_match pattern next line two first words

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have this preg_match pattern `` `/admin[^:]*:\s*(.* )/i `` for this subject(as sample)

```
txt stuff
Administrative Contact:
Brown, John support@xxxxxxx.com
txt stuff
```

to pull out "Brown, John support@xxxxxxx.com" but I need something to search and print "Brown, John" (name) only and not the whole line (everything as name but not email).
This is a piece of large text and the only static string is "Administrative Contact:".

Thanks

Comment: How about `([^,]*?, [^\s]*?)` instead of `(.*)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://ideone.com/u0UgL

```
$str = 'txt stuff
Administrative Contact:
Brown, John support@xxxxxxx.com
txt stuff';

preg_match('~admin[^:]*:\s*(.*)\s+\S+@~i', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]); // string(11) "Brown, John"
```

Comment: You meant "buddy"? ;-) PS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820236/preg-match-for-next-line#comment14087305_10820281 -- oh, I'm not the only "body" here :-S